# Export frequencies tables and histogram to excel sheets in macro

Tags: loops, macros, export-to-excel, spss

I'm trying to export the table and histogram created through a loop, each to different excel sheets. It works, but only the first histogram gets exported even though all of them get created in different result windows. In the rest of the sheets an "image currently unavailable" message appears, but the table part is saved properly. These are the macros:

```
DEFINE create (!POS !CHAREND('/'))
!DO !i !IN (!1)
   OUTPUT NEW.
   OUTPUT NAME !i.
   FREQUENCIES VARIABLES=!i
  /FORMAT=NOTABLE
  /PERCENTILES=1.0 99.0
  /STATISTICS=STDDEV MINIMUM MAXIMUM MEAN MEDIAN KURTOSIS SEKURT
  /HISTOGRAM NORMAL
  /ORDER=ANALYSIS.
 !DOEND
!ENDDEFINE.

DEFINE save (!POS !CHAREND('/'))
!DO !i !IN (!1)
OUTPUT EXPORT NAME = !i
  /CONTENTS  EXPORT=ALL  LAYERS=ALL  MODELVIEWS=ALL
  /XLS  DOCUMENTFILE='C:\Users\Ildefonso\Documents\OUTPUT.xls'
     OPERATION=CREATESHEET SHEET=!quote(!concat(!i))
     LOCATION=LASTCOLUMN  NOTESCAPTIONS=YES.
   !DOEND
!ENDDEFINE.

create var1 var2/.
save var1 var2 /.
```

Any evident mistake I am making? Or a more SPSS-way of going about it? I need to solve this without installing anything extra. I am using spss v22 on windows 10.

Comment: I ran your code - version 23 win 10 - all worked fine (also with 5 variables)...

Comment: I would try combining the macros and doing everything in the same loop - this way you create and save each output separately, maybe that will help.          In any case, a couple of unrelated comments - (1) I don't recommend using words like "save" and "create" for macro names, as they are parts of SPSS commands. (2) why `!quote(!concat(!i))`? just use `!quote(!i)' (3) you don't need `!CHAREND('/')` in this case - just use `!cmdend`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I had all the code in one macro but split it to make sure the output was coming out in different windows. The names were not the actual macro names but I'll keep in mind avoiding conflict with existing SPSS commands. Does my approach to this seem like the way to do it? I need to solve this issue and can't update SPSS :/.

Comment: I see no problem with your general approach. Sorry can't help bc version gap - anyone else?

Comment: Just an idea: have you installed all patches to SPSS 20? They are freely available on IBM website. The initial release was indeed very buggy, but a lot of bugs were fixed via patches